# How to show different sidebar or sidebar items based on user in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am creating two different dashboards for two sets of users and I want to show a different Side nav for each. I tried the method below which shows the admin sidenav only on their pages but when I tried that method with the other sidenav it still only shows the first sidenav for both users.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { routes } from './components/pages/routes';
import { navroutes } from './components/pages/routes';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { SideNav } from './components/SideNav';
import './custom.css'

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render () {
    return (
        <Router>

            <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, index) => (
                    <Route
                        key={index}
                        path={route.path}
                        exact={route.exact}
                        component={route.main}
                    />
                    ))}
                <div className="navwrapper">
                    <SideNav />
                    {navroutes.map((route, index) => (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            component={route.main}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>

            </Switch>
        </Router>
       
    );
  }
}
```